# Редирект при неверном маршруте

Tags: php, yii2, framework

Всем привет!
Подскажите пожалуйста как в yii2 можно обработать ошибку 404.
Мне нужно при неверном маршруте, сделать редирект с этим же маршрутом только на другой домен.
К примеру:
newsite.ru/a/b/c -если эта ссылка окажется не верной, то обработчик на newsite(работает на  yii2) должен сделать редирект на oldsite.ru/a/b/c.

Comment: ну так когда у вас 404 срабатывает какойто event в yii ловите его иделайте тупой `header('Location:http://oldiste.ru'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])`. Но перед этим стоит запросить страницу с старого сайта штобы не было редиректа на 404.

Comment: Проблема в том что я не знаю как поймать это event.

Comment: смотрите в yii есть exception http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-invalidrouteexception.html т.е. можно его отловить и уже там опреировать.

Comment: Тогда еще вопрос: где ловить это исключение? т.е. в каком методе?

Comment: Тут я думаю надо дождаться спецов по yii я с ним не работал но в принципе можно прям в index.php попробывать `try{}cath(invalidRouteException $error) {}` поймать. Но опять же стоит дождаться опытных спецов в этом деле.

Comment: То есть если action вернет 404, то срабатывает редирект? Я правильно Вас понял?

Comment: Да, все правильно

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Пока сделал так:
В конфиге указал экшен-обработчик

```
   'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'user/error'
    ],
```

В экшене-обработчике

```
public function actionError()
{

    $exception = Yii::$app->errorHandler->exception;
    if ($exception !== null) {
        if ($exception->statusCode === 404) {
            //Меняем statusCode 3
            $exception->statusCode = 301;
            return $this->redirect('http://oldsite.ru' . Yii::$app->request->url, 301);
        }
        return $this->render('/site/error', ['exception' => $exception]);
    }
}
```

Но мне это решение не нравится. Хотелось бы не создавать обработчик в контроллере, а вынести его куда то в более независимое место.

Comment: А что мешает наследовать yii\base\controller и прописать в нем actionError, а свои контроллеры наследовать уже от последнего? Таким образом во всех контроллерах будет присутствовать экшн ошибки, который можно поправить в одном месте.

Comment: Об этом тоже думал, но у меня базовый контроллер лежит в common/controllers/. Если я укажу этот путь в errorHandler то думаю yii не сможет его найти.

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-web-erroraction.html В документации написано как указать класс обработки ошибок через actions в контроллере.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что можно еще в конфиге приложения посмотреть в сторону события
`"as afterRequest"`, и в нем проверять пришел ответ 200 или 404.
Либо сделать так, как Вы написали выше.